# Compute eigenvalues for 5x5 matrix given nullity

Tags: linear-algebra

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9n7Z.png)

The given matrix is linearly dependent and has rank 1 and nullity 4. How does this help in finding the eigenvalues?

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel is the eigenspace with respect to the zero eigenvalue. Since the dimension of the kernel is $4$, you have that the matrix has the eigenvalue $\lambda = 0$ with multiplicity at least 4.

You have also shown that the matrix has dimension of its range equal to 1, so it was some non-zero eigenvalue and the zero eigenvalue has multiplicity $4$. You can determine the last eigenvalue from the fact that the trace of the matrix is equal to the sum of the eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! :)